# How to call a javascript function and get the html code it returns ,Java,Android

Tags: java, javascript, android

There is a HTML page that has a javascript function in it.This function returns a frame with a random picture.
Is there a way to call this function and get the HTML code that is hidding? (So i get the image)

Exactly i want to get a html stream from [GoogleServices.js](http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js)
by calling:

```
GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-YOU
RPUBIDHERE");
  GS_googleEnableAllServices();
  GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-YOURPUBIDHERE", "ADSLOT_NAME_HERE");
  GA_googleFetchAds();
GA_googleFillSlot("ADSLOT_NAME_HERE");
```

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?  How does your question relate to Java and Android?  Maybe posting some of the code you have tried would help put this into context...

Comment: Well finally i came accross with admob home ads that was what i was looking for at the end!

Answer (score 1):

An example of how Java and JavaScript can call each other using a WebView in Android can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java

Comment: i was looking at that before, didn't help me.Even if i got the webview to return the right content how could i take the code?